# Buying Uzbek Rail Tickets

Tags: trains, uzbekistan

I am trying to book trains in Uzbekistan but the Uzbek rail web-site will not work for me. I will have to use expensive web bookers. There appear to be three main sites: Advantour, Caravanistan and Peopletravel. Does anyone have recommendations or reviews from personal experience of these ticket providers please?

Comment: Can't speak for online bookings, but when I did it in 2011, I'd go to the station the day before and buy tickets without problem.

Comment: Unfortunately the seats and berths I need tend to sell out in advance in September.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search on Google got me the site [railway.uz](http://railway.uz/en/). Seems pretty official to me and the site is linked by [Seat61](https://www.seat61.com/Uzbekistan.htm).

There's a link to online booking there.

Comment: I cannot use them. The ticket purchase url is https://eticket.uzrailway.uz/main.html.  I registered weeks ago and attempted to purchase several times since the date for purchase arrived. I cannot get past the seat selection and passenger details page. I have emailed them several times but they never answer. Also the terms and conditions suggest they will not accept my Debit mastercard. I also tried using the Kazakh system which works fine but requires ticket pickup from a Kazakh rail station. I will not enter Kazakhstan until after Uzbekistan.

Comment: PS. Another difficulty is that the high speed Afrosiyab trains I wish to book are not appearing on their site.

Comment: @Alan, yeah, they had "test" in the name of the link to the booking. Since it seems hard to buy the tickets online maybe you could just buy them at the station?

Comment: Can RZD sell them by any chance?